# Get Current URL (UIWebView)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, url, uiwebview

Simply enough, I need to know how to obtain the current URL that the UIWebView is in. That way, I would be able to add such features as bookmarking, sharing, etc.

The crux of the question is, what can I do to obtain the current URL of the webvew?

EDIT: Solution:

```
NSString *currentURL = myWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
NSString *currentURL = myWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[[[web request] URL] absoluteString]
```

Will give you the current url as a String.

Comment: Thank you for putting the Objective-c version as an answer here!

Answer (score 2):

In Swift if you need to get your URL you need to write this block of code:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let currentURL = webView.request?.mainDocumentURL
    print(currentURL)
}
```